# C# filling TableLayoutPanel cells from left to right

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout

I am working on a windows form app which primarily consists of a TableLayoutPanel with 8 columns and 9 rows. I have been able to fill each of the cells like so:

```
for (int row = 0; row < TableLayoutPanel.RowCount; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; column++) {
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox, column, row);
        pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pictureBox.Margin = new Padding(1);
}
```

However this method starts from the top than goes left to right downwards like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

My aim is to fill the TableLayoutPanel like:

```
6 5 4
1 2 3
```

I don't know if this is possible but is there a way to do fill the TableLayoutPanel cells in this fashion?

Comment: So you want to fill in a "snake" shape? Nth row left to right, N-1th row right to left, N-2th row left to right, etc?

Comment: Yeah, because I am making something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry guys I figured out how to do it. What I did was that I started from the bottom row of the `TableLayoutPanel` (in my case was row = 8) and worked up from there. I than determined if the row values were odd or even in which case I would change the direction. Here is the solution.

```
for (int row = TableLayoutPanel.RowCount-1; row >= 0; row--) {
    if (row % 2 == 0) { //if even
        for (int column = 0; column < TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; column++) {
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox, column, row);
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.Margin = new Padding(1);
    } else { 
        for (int column = TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount-1; column >= 0; column--) {
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox, column, row);
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.Margin = new Padding(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your for loops with:

```
for (int row = TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1, c0 = 0, c1 = TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount - 1, cs = 1; row >= 0 ; row--, c0 ^= c1, c1 ^= c0, c0 ^= c1, cs *= -1)
{
    for (int column = c0; column != c1 + cs; column += cs)
    {
         ...
```